# Serde Bytes unable to serialize / deserialize

Tags: rust, serialization

I've decided to try out serde for network packet serialization, but it's a pain.

I've been unable to serialize an Enum at all, and I keep getting errors. I can't find a working example online either, there are none in the [doc](https://docs.rs/serde_bytes/latest/serde_bytes/) nor in the [repo](https://github.com/serde-rs/bytes).

That's why I'm looking for :

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

use super::{ClientMessage, ServerMessage};

/// The different messages that can be sent from the client to the lobby.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum ClientToLobbyMessage {
    Quit,
    CreateRoom,
    JoinRoom(RoomId),
}

impl ClientMessage for ClientToLobbyMessage {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<ClientToLobbyMessage> {
        serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
    }
}
```

This gives a compile-time error : the trait bound `ClientToLobbyMessage: serde_bytes::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied.

Adding the the `#[serde(with = "serde_bytes")]` above the enum fields won't work either:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

use super::{ClientMessage, ServerMessage};

/// The different messages that can be sent from the client to the lobby.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum ClientToLobbyMessage {
    #[serde(with = "serde_bytes")]
    Quit,
    #[serde(with = "serde_bytes")]
    CreateRoom,
    #[serde(with = "serde_bytes")]
    JoinRoom(RoomId),
}
```

This gives an error on the derive macros: this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied on the `Serialize`, and the trait bound `(): serde_bytes::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied for the `Deserialize`.

Finally, I can't find derive macros in the serde_bytes package, as `use serde_bytes::{Serialize, Deserialize};` states : `Serialize` is imported here, but it is only a trait, without a derive macro.

The `Cargo.toml` file looks like :

```yaml
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.178", features = ["derive"] }
serde_bytes = "0.11.12"
```

And any try to add features to serde_bytes like I did with serde resulted in:
failed to select a version for `serde_bytes` which could resolve this conflict error.

I really hope I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm kinda desappointed as I heard that serde was super easy to use.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to treat serde-bytes like its a data format, but it is not. It is only used to *augment* how `Vec<u8>` and `&[u8]` are serialized and deserialized to be more efficient. If you need something that can work with arbitrary serde data types, consider using [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) (which uses serde-bytes internally).

Comment: @kmdreko I'm trying to serialize enums to bytes. Does bincode ensure that serialized content will be deserialized to the same content, through the network ?

Comment: Yes. It would be unusable if it didn't ensure round-trip equality.

Comment: If you show error messages, please show the full error from `cargo check` instead of a on-liner from the IDE.

Comment: Please make your example an [mre]. I can't reproduce your error because `ClientMessage`, `ServerMessage` and `RoomId` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example is incomplete, I will assume your example is:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

trait ClientMessage: Sized {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<Self>;
}

/// The different messages that can be sent from the client to the lobby.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum ClientToLobbyMessage {
    Quit,
    CreateRoom,
    JoinRoom(i32),
}

impl ClientMessage for ClientToLobbyMessage {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<ClientToLobbyMessage> {
        serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
    }
}
```

Which produces this monstrousity of an error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&[u8]: Deserializer<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:17:34
    |
17  |         serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
    |         ------------------------ ^^^^^ the trait `Deserializer<'_>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
    |         |
    |         required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserializer<'de>`:
              UnitDeserializer<E>
              U32Deserializer<E>
              _::_serde::de::value::StrDeserializer<'a, E>
              _::_serde::de::value::BorrowedStrDeserializer<'de, E>
              StringDeserializer<E>
              CowStrDeserializer<'a, E>
              BytesDeserializer<'a, E>
              BorrowedBytesDeserializer<'de, E>
            and 25 others
note: required by a bound in `serde_bytes::deserialize`
   --> C:\Users\Finomnis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde_bytes-0.11.12\src\lib.rs:110:8
    |
107 | pub fn deserialize<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
    |        ----------- required by a bound in this function
...
110 |     D: Deserializer<'de>,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `deserialize`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&[u8]: Deserializer<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src\lib.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserializer<'_>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserializer<'de>`:
             UnitDeserializer<E>
             U32Deserializer<E>
             _::_serde::de::value::StrDeserializer<'a, E>
             _::_serde::de::value::BorrowedStrDeserializer<'de, E>
             StringDeserializer<E>
             CowStrDeserializer<'a, E>
             BytesDeserializer<'a, E>
             BorrowedBytesDeserializer<'de, E>
           and 25 others

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ClientToLobbyMessage: serde_bytes::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:17:9
    |
17  |         serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde_bytes::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `ClientToLobbyMessage`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `serde_bytes::Deserialize<'de>`:
              Box<serde_bytes::Bytes>
              Box<[u8]>
              serde_bytes::ByteBuf
              Cow<'a, [u8]>
              Cow<'a, serde_bytes::Bytes>
              Vec<u8>
              std::option::Option<T>
              &'a [u8]
              &'a serde_bytes::Bytes
note: required by a bound in `serde_bytes::deserialize`
   --> C:\Users\Finomnis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde_bytes-0.11.12\src\lib.rs:109:8
    |
107 | pub fn deserialize<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
    |        ----------- required by a bound in this function
108 | where
109 |     T: Deserialize<'de>,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `deserialize`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&[u8]: Deserializer<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src\lib.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         serde_bytes::deserialize(bytes).ok()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserializer<'_>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserializer<'de>`:
             UnitDeserializer<E>
             U32Deserializer<E>
             _::_serde::de::value::StrDeserializer<'a, E>
             _::_serde::de::value::BorrowedStrDeserializer<'de, E>
             StringDeserializer<E>
             CowStrDeserializer<'a, E>
             BytesDeserializer<'a, E>
             BorrowedBytesDeserializer<'de, E>
           and 25 others
```

Your mistake is that you use `serde_bytes` as if it were a data format, which it is not. It seems to be a helper library for `serde` for handling byte array types.

As suggested by @kmdreko, you could use the [`bincode`](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.3.3/bincode/) format instead. This one is an actual encoding.

Like this:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

trait ClientMessage: Sized {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<Self>;
}

/// The different messages that can be sent from the client to the lobby.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum ClientToLobbyMessage {
    Quit,
    CreateRoom,
    JoinRoom(i32),
}

impl ClientMessage for ClientToLobbyMessage {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<ClientToLobbyMessage> {
        bincode::deserialize(bytes).ok()
    }
}
```